# Warning redefined-outer-name unexpectedly silenced

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

By default, pylint v2.9.6 gives this warning:

**spam.py**

```
"""Docstring."""


def spam():
    """Docstring."""
    spam = 42
    return spam
```

**pylint warning**

```
spam.py|6 col 5 warning| [redefined-outer-name] Redefining name 'spam' from outer scope (line 4) [python/pylint]
```

After creating the following .pylintrc, the warning is no longer given.  This is not desired.

**.pylintrc** ([possible locations](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options))

```
[VARIABLES]

# A regular expression matching the name of dummy variables (i.e. expected to
# not be used).
#dummy-variables-rgx=_+$|(_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+?$)|dummy|^ignored_|^unused_
dummy-variables-rgx=
```

Why?

Comment: You have defined *every possible variable name* to be a dummy variable - is that really what you intended?

Comment: Oh, is that the case? No, my intention is have no identifiers be considered dummy variables. What should I do instead?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea (a dummy variable is exactly what you need, sometimes), but I think `^$` would do the job - that only matches strings with zero length.

Comment: `dummy-variables-rgx=^$` also seems to resolve the error silencing.  I'll be defining dummy variables as required, so I will keep your advice in mind.